# how to delete specified character in array and copy the elements to another array

Tags: java, arrays, string, error-handling

how to delete specified character in array and copy the elements of the first array to the second array ?

i tried to convert the array to a list to be able to check if the array contain this specified character, then i tried to remove this character and create another array by copying the element of the first array but without the specified character.

the system display this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:375)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.remove(AbstractCollection.java:269)
    at test4.test4.main(Question4.java:21)
```

## this is my code:

```
package test4;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class test4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] a = new String[]{ "A", "b", "C", "$", "$", "$", "d", "s", "w", "t", "Z",
                "r", "I", "o", "A", "b", "C", "$", "$", "$", "d", "s", "w", "t" };

        String[] b = new String[a.length];
        int num = 0;
        for(int i =0; i<a.length; i++){

            if(Character.isUpperCase(i)){
                num++;
            }
            if(Arrays.asList(a).contains("$")){

                Arrays.asList(a).remove("$");
                b[i] =a[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("number os uperCase is: " + num);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("this is the new Array: " + Arrays.toString(b));

    }

}
```

can anyone help me to fix this problem??

Comment: Arrays.asList() returns a fixed length List, so removing an element is not allowed. You have to use `new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(a));`

Comment: so where to use this statement in my code ??

Comment: I don't know. I don't really understand your code. If you want to remove every `$` from your `List` it would be better to do it separately from the loop that counts upper case letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(a)` returns a list of fixed length, so `Arrays.asList(a).remove("$");` can't work.

You can iterate over the array instead :

```
    int count = 0;
    for(int i =0; i<a.length; i++){
        if(Character.isUpperCase(a[i].charAt(0))){
            num++;
        }
        if(!a[i].equals("$")){ // copy only non "$" Strings to the output array
            b[count] =a[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Note that your count of upper case characters was also wrong, since you were calling `Character.isUpperCase` on indices of the array instead of the characters contained in it.

Another thing you should consider is changing `String[] a` to `char[] a`, since it looks like you only have single character Strings in that array.

Comment: It's not immutable, it's fixed length. You can set an element.

Comment: No worries :) I thought that it was immutable for ages, as I hardly ever use `set`.

Comment: thank you Eran i fixed the uperCase  but the new array still display null instead of the **"$"**  can i remove the null ??

Comment: @javadev The output array `b` has the same length as the input array `a`. Therefore, for each $ that appears in `a`, there would be a `null` at the end of `b`. If you wish to get rid of the `null`s, you can copy `b` to a 3rd array, whose length is `count`. You only have to copy the first `count` elements.

Comment: `String[] a1 = new String[]{ "A", "b"}`, `List<String> l = Arrays.asList(a1);` working fine there is no any exception but when we put "$" in array it will give us unsupported exception why?

Comment: @atishshimpi You can't add or remove elements from a list that was returned by Arrays.asList, since it doesn't support those operations.

Comment: is it unmodifiable list?

Comment: @atishshimpi You can modify it using `set`, but you can't add or remove elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm REALLY new at Java and this is the first Question I've answered, so I'm sorry if I'm wrong. Here it goes: 
Character.isUpperCase() can not check against a String. It can only check against a char. So I would change the array from a String to char (' instead of " for each character).
Second, the if statement needs to check a[i] not just i.
Third, I would make your second array an ArrayList and convert each char to be added toString so that the size of the second array wouldn't matter and can be used with different arrays.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class test4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] a = new char[]{ 'A', 'b', 'C', '$', '$', '$', 'd', 's', 'w', 't', 'Z',
            'r', 'I', 'o', 'A', 'b', 'C', '$', '$', '$', 'd', 's', 'w', 't' };

    ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<>();
    int num = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){

        if(Character.isUpperCase(a[i])){
            num++;
        }

        if(Arrays.asList(a[i]).contains('$')){

        }
        else{
            String conv = Character.toString(a[i]);
            b.add(conv);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("number of upperCase is: " + num);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("This is the new Array: " );
    for(String value: b ){
        System.out.print(value + " ");
    }
}
```

}